# How do i Integrate vi editor with google docs

Tags: linux, unix, google-docs, vi, google-docs-api

Is there a way to integrate vi editor with Google documents? Basically it should work like this:

1. Open vi editor on one machine and type the contents.
2. The contents typed on the vi editor should be displayed on the Google docs [which can be viewed on another computer]

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you install [googlecl](https://code.google.com/p/googlecl/)? You can edit a google doc using Vi with a command like this:

```
$ google docs edit --title "Document Title" --editor vi
```

You can find more information on this [here](https://code.google.com/p/googlecl/wiki/Manual#Docs).

Comment: For the record, this solution isn't great. If someone edits the doc while you've got it open in vim then your work won't be saved.